# select based on one field association with multiple values in another field

Tags: sql, oracle

I neeed to develop a script that will capture all fields when one car is tied to more than one color.

If one car is tied to one color more than once, that needs to be captured only if that car is tied to additional colors.

If one car is tied to one color more than once and no other colors that does NOT need to be captured.

```
  {CREATE TABLE test2
(
  ID     NUMBER(9),
  CAR    NUMBER(9),
  COLOR  NUMBER(9)
);


Insert into test2 (ID, CAR, COLOR) Values (1,  5, 10);
Insert into test2 (ID, CAR, COLOR) Values (2,  5, 11);
Insert into test2 (ID, CAR, COLOR) Values (3,  5, 10);
Insert into test2 (ID, CAR, COLOR) Values (4,  9, 6);
Insert into test2 (ID, CAR, COLOR) Values (5,  9, 6);
Insert into test2 (ID, CAR, COLOR) Values (6,  8, 4);
Insert into test2 (ID, CAR, COLOR) Values (7,  8, 9);
Insert into test2 (ID, CAR, COLOR) Values (8, 12, 9);
COMMIT;}



--expected results
  ID          CAR           COLOR
   1            5              10
   2            5              11
   3            5              10
   6            8               4
   7            8               4
```

all insights and suggestions deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use either an `in` clause or a correlated `exists` clause. The latter should perform better than the former:

```
select id, car, color from test2
where car in (
    select car 
    from test2 
    group by car 
    having count(distinct color) > 1
)

select id, car, color from test2 t
where exists (
    select car 
    from test2 
    where car = t.car
    group by car 
    having count(distinct color) > 1
)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5813/1)

Comment: great. having all features in mind when writing queries is really important, I just hadn't `count(distinct` in mind while writing my answer, while I'm using it frequently.

Comment: jpw,That works great and performs far faster on the larger real example.   Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform a `count` twice:

```
with cte as 
(  select CAR,COLOR,count(*) cn
   from test2
   group by CAR,COLOR 
 )
select t.id,t.car,t.color  
from test2 t
join( 
   select car,count(*)
   from cte
   group by CAR
   having count(*)>1)q
on t.car=q.car
order by 1
```

*OUTPUT:*

```
ID  CAR COLOR
1   5   10
2   5   11
3   5   10
6   8   4
7   8   9
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need all cars except those have only one distinct color:
(Alternative for other answer but very simple)

```
select *
from test2
where not car in (select car from test2 group by car having count(distinct color = 1))
```